# XOR big number from m to n

Tags: summation, algorithms

Problem : Given a range $[n,m]$, find the xor of all numbers in this range. Constraints : $1 \le n \le m \le 10^{18}$

^ = xor

2120^2121^2122^....^200000006000

How do we solve this problem?

Comment: Bit by bit.${}$

Comment: @TonyK - That cracked me up.

Comment: @TonyK Please explain

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre could you explain?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670379/find-xor-of-all-numbers-in-a-given-range

Comment: You know what a bit is, right? Evaluate the answer one bit at a time.

Comment: In fact, I take that back! @Domnik's link gives a super-clever method to evaluate the result directly, in about 20 machine cycles.

Comment: @TonyK this method is good for 4 bit data. Is it work on 8 bit data?

Comment: It works on 2048-bit data. Or 1428594867352-bit data.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. I use it and perfectly worked. Only problem is in some cases answer is negative not positive. Is it regular or  not?